# $RL$ Circuit Initial Condition - Why is $I$ continuous?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

In a simple $RL$ circuit with a switch, the switch is closed at $t = 0$. Then the differential equation we are solving is $V_0 -L \frac{dI}{dt} = IR_0$, and the solution is $I(t)=\frac{V_0}{R_0}+ke^{-\frac{R}{L}t}$.

Here's where I'm confused: The initial condition is $I(0^{-}) = 0$ (because the switch is open), and based on this the textbook concludes that $k=-\frac{V_0}{R_0}$. But how can we rigorously prove that there is no discontinuity in $I$ between $0^{-}$ and $0^{+}$? For example, if there was no inductor in this circuit, then $I(0^{-}) = 0$ and $I(0^{+})=\frac{V_0}{R_0}$, so clearly the initial condition had no effect on the solution. In fact, it seems to me that the solution to the RL circuit's differential equation is only valid for $t \geq 0^{+}$, because $R(0^{-})=\infty$ (before the switch is closed) and therefore the integration would not be possible. So how are we certain that there is no discontinuity in $I(t)$ at $t=0$, even though there is when there is no inductor? If there was, and $I(0^{+})$ was nonzero, then the rate of change of $I$ for all $t$ would be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how can we rigorously prove that there is no discontinuity in $I$
> between $0^{-}$ and $0^{+}$?

For an ideal inductor, the current cannot theoretically change instantaneously, i.e., change in zero time. Thus

$$I_{L}(0+)=I_{L}(0-)$$

This follows from the basic relationship between voltage and current for an ideal inductor

$$v_{L}(t)=L\frac{di_{L}(t)}{dt}$$ or

$$di_{L}(t)=\frac{1}{L} v_{L}(t)dt$$

Thus as $dt\rightarrow 0$, $di_{L}(t)\rightarrow 0$

> For example, if there was no inductor in this circuit, then $I(0^{-})
> > = 0$ and $I(0^{+})=\frac{V_0}{R_0}$, so clearly the initial condition had no effect on the solution.

For an ideal resistor, the current can theoretically change instantaneously.
In reality, however, there are no ideal resistors. Any conductor has some self inductance. But in many cases it is so small that it can be ignored.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When there is no inductor in the circuit, only a resistor, then there is no differential equation and no initial condition associated with it. You have a DE because of the inductor.
Because of the switch, formally, you have a time varying (differential) equation that changes at $t=0$. One way to see this is to add an enormous resistor $R_{big}$ in parallel with the switch, so that from $t=-\infty$ and on you have a very small current $I_{small}=\tfrac{V_0}{R_{big}}$ flowing through the inductor. Now  at $t=0$ the switch is flipped and the $R_{big}$ is shorted but the current must start to change from $I_{small}$ to $\tfrac{V_0}{R_{0}}$

Answer (score 1):

The relationship that you found for the current in an LR circuit is $I(t)=\dfrac{V_0}{R_0}\left(1-e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\right)$ which predicts that the current at $t=0$ is zero.
So there is no discontinuity.

Neither is the is discontinuity in the current if there is only a resistor in the circuit as there must also be some inductance.
There is inductance because the circuit forms a loop and so the same current time relationship hold be it with a small value of inductance.
You might not observe the delay in the current reaching a value of $\frac{V_0}{R_0}$ because the inductance of the circuit loop will be small but not zero.
For example for a circular loop of diameter $15\,\rm cm$ the inductance is approximately $1\,\rm \mu H$.
Thus, if the total resistance of the loop is $1\,\rm k\Omega$, the time constant of the circuit is $\frac LR = 1\,\rm ns$.